# Present State of Random Number Generator in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, verification, register-transfer-level, system-verilog

How we can get the present state or present seed of Random number generator in system verilog??

Answer (score 3):

Use `get_randstate()`, which is defined as

```
function string get_randstate();
```

From the SystemVerilog 2012 language spec:

> The `get_randstate()` method returns a copy of the internal state of the RNG associated with the given object. The RNG state is a string of unspecified length and format. The length and contents of the string are implementation dependent.

Note that SystemVerilog will create a separate RNG for each thread and object, so you'll see different results from different objects.

Example:

```
t1 = new;
t2 = new;
$display(t1.get_randstate());
$display(t2.get_randstate());
```

Sample output from Incisive:

```
svseed=1 ; 5864a323c57f14c ; 
svseed=1 ; bbfc1b9e8eb663ae ;
```